# Decrypt base64 and save in second variable

Tags: bash, shell, encryption, base64

I am trying to write a password security system. (Just a small homesystem to learn some bash scripting) I am able to encrypt the password string and save it to another file.

My next step is to export these encrypted password strings in my shell script and decrypt them to use them in this routine. I found an export solution with simple export commands and I finally saved the encrypted strings to new variables.

How can I decrypt these strings and save them in another variable. I am using openssl and base64 encryption.

This is the source code:

```
export user=$(cat logindata | head -n1 | tail -n1)
export passwd=$(cat logindata | head -n2 | tail -n1)
passwd2=echo -n $passwd | openssl enc -d -base64
echo "$user"
echo "$passwd2"
```

Comment: Whoever reads this should be aware that base64 is not an actually [encryption](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/encryption), it is just binary-to-text encoding.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This script would give the concept:

```
#!/bin/sh

username='my_username'
password='my_password'

username_encoded=$(echo -n "$username" | openssl enc -base64)
password_encoded=$(echo -n "$password" | openssl enc -base64)

username_decoded=$(echo "$username_encoded" | openssl enc -d -base64)
password_decoded=$(echo "$password_encoded" | openssl enc -d -base64)

echo "username: $username"
echo "username_encoded: $username_encoded"
echo "username_decoded: $username_decoded"
echo "password: $password"
echo "password_encoded: $password_encoded"
echo "password_decoded: $password_decoded"
```

Output:

```
username: my_username
username_encoded: bXlfdXNlcm5hbWU=
username_decoded: my_username
password: my_password
password_encoded: bXlfcGFzc3dvcmQ=
password_decoded: my_password
```

Notice that when decoding, you need to send a newline at the end that's why I didn't use `-n` with echo.